# Android Countdown Issue

Tags: android

I've been working on a live ticker and with the help of some code I found on the internet i've managed to find something that is sort of working.

I'm getting a date out of a database and splitting it and putting it into milliseconds and this is where the code I found takes over.

Now the rest of it works out perfect except for the days, it seems to be always 30 days plus however many is left??

This is the code:

```
        GregorianCalendar endDate = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(separated[0]), Integer.parseInt(separated[1]),  Integer.parseInt(separated[2]), Integer.parseInt(Time[0]), Integer.parseInt(Time[1]), 00);
    GregorianCalendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds);

    long diffInMs = endDate.getTimeInMillis() - startDate.getTimeInMillis();


    new CountDownTimer(diffInMs, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 
             int seconds = (int)(millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60 ;
             int minutes = (int)((millisUntilFinished / (1000*60)) % 60);
             int hours = (int)((millisUntilFinished / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
             int days = (int)((millisUntilFinished / (1000*60*60*24)) % 365);
             //int years = (int)(millisUntilFinished / 1000*60*60*24*365);

             ArrayList<String> timeArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    //               if(years > 0)   
    //                   timeArray.add(String.valueOf(years)   + "y");

             if(days > 0)    
                 timeArray.add(String.valueOf(days) + "d");

             if(hours>0)   
                 timeArray.add(String.valueOf(hours) + "h");

             if(minutes>0) 
                 timeArray.add(String.valueOf(minutes) + "min");

             if(seconds>0) 
                 timeArray.add(String.valueOf(seconds) + "sec");

             String time = "";
             for (int i = 0; i < timeArray.size(); i++) 
             {
                 time = time + timeArray.get(i);
                 if (i != timeArray.size() - 1)
                     time = time + ", ";
             }

             if (time == "")
               time = "0 sec";

             Countdown.setText("Database Lock: " + time );


         }
```

Now I can't see why the days would work out wrong?

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I tried your code and it works just fine. Give an example of an input value that gives the wrong result.

Comment: Well it's pulling this date out of the database 2012-07-07 13:00:00 then splitting the date part up, i've made a slight alteration to stop it crashing because it was trying to put the time on and then it adds the time on after. Anyway it says like 38d, 23h, 31min, 20sec??

Comment: I've figured out why I was getting an incorrect countdown on the days.. It is to do with this: int month = gregorianCalendar.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH); It seems this part is giving the incorrect month?? Its giving it 5 and not 6??

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to take a days, hour, minutes, second different than this is code is working for me.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class DateDiff{ 

  public static void main(String[] args){

  Date date = null;
  Date date1 = new Date();
  System.out.println(date1.toString());


  try { 
  String str_date="Tue, 25 Jun 2012 05:43:27";
  DateFormat formatter ;
  //Date date ;
  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,dd MMM yy HH:mm:ss");
  date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date); 
  System.out.println("Today is " +date );
  } catch (ParseException e)
   {

     System.out.println("Exception :"+e); 

  } 

  long diff = date1.getTime() - date.getTime();
  long seconds = diff / 1000;
  long minutes = seconds / 60;
  long hours = minutes / 60;
  long days = hours / 24;


       System.out.println("Time in seconds: " + seconds
      + " seconds.");
       System.out.println("Time in minutes: " + minutes
     + " minutes.");
       System.out.println("Time in hours: " + hours
     + " hours.");
       System.out.println("Time in days: " +days
     + " days.");



  }
}
```